# Finding and extracting an email address using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, search, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

Within HTML code, I am trying to extract an email address only if it is provided by the user. Here is a sample of the HTML:

```
<div class="header">
 <div class="details">
   <span>
     <!-- Random description here which MAY contain an email address -->
   </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have managed to get to `<span>`by using HTML Agility Pack as follows:

```
var getWeb = new HtmlWeb();
var pageHtml = getWeb.Load("website here");
IEnumerable<string> listItemHtml = pageHtml.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
                    @"//div[@class='header']
                    /div[@class='details']
                    /span").Select(span => span.InnerText);
```

My next challenge is to search through this text and check if an email has been provided, which I am unable to figure out. Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: You **could** use a regexp but then you'd have the regexp as a second problem :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-email-address-in-javascript)